# How to execute setTimeout function immediately after the delay?

Tags: javascript

I want to execute setTimeout after the delay and not wait for it to be called from the message queue after all the other functions have executed. Please refer the code below:

```
let test = function(){ console.log('test') }
setTimeout(() => console.log('hi'), 2000)

test();
test();
test();
.
.
.
.
this code takes more than 2 seconds to execute;
```

How to get setTimeout after 2 seconds instead of at the end ?

Comment: Even other non-event based execution also doesn't guarantee that the code will for sure be executed at some exact time.
However to get close to a 2 second delay, you can have a 1.5 seconds delay and then run a while loop which will block other execution, have a counter of what 2 seconds delay would be in milliseconds, check for the time in milliseconds and then run the code.

Comment: for that to happen, your code needs to be asynchronous so that they can add any other function in stack

Comment: If you are blocking thread, there is no way other code could run. You must have all of the subsequent code be non-blocking then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would mention that if those `test()` calls do not perform DOM operations you could possibly move them to a worker.

[Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) allow running code on a background thread that doesn't block your main UI thread.
I've created a quick example that runs a synchronous task of arbitrary duration on a worker thread. On the main thread `setInterval` and `setTimeout` calls are running uninterrupted.

[See it in action.](https://codesandbox.io/s/2v96n0yvkr?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14)

**index.js**

```
let interval = setInterval(() => console.log("Not blocked"), 500);

console.log("Scheduling to run in 2 seconds");
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("2 seconds passed. Running scheduled task! ");
}, 2000);

let longTaskRunner = new Worker("./src/worker.js");
let taskDuration = 3;
console.log(
  `Starting synchronous task that takes more than ${taskDuration} seconds`
);

longTaskRunner.postMessage(taskDuration);
longTaskRunner.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log(`Long task completed in ${e.data} seconds`);
  clearInterval(interval);
};
longTaskRunner.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
};
```

**worker.js**

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {
  const runFor = e.data * 1000;
  let startedAt = Date.now();
  let timeElapsed = 0;

  while (timeElapsed < runFor) {
    timeElapsed = Date.now() - startedAt;
  }

  self.postMessage(timeElapsed / 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not need `setTimeout`. Instead return a `promise` from `test` function and do rest of the things inside `then` which will only work once `test` is resolved

```js
let test = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('test');
    resolve('test executed')
  })
}


test().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the chain of `test`s is consuming more than 2000ms of CPU time synchronously ("blocking"), I don't think it's possible like that - the best you could do is check in `test` (or in a function wrapped around it) whether the time difference between the start (where your `setTimeout` is currently) and the current time is more than 2 seconds - if so, execute the function. For example:

```
console.log('start');
let hasRun = false;
const fnToRunLater = () => console.log('hi');
const startTime = Date.now();
function test() {
  const now = Date.now();
  if (!hasRun && now - startTime > 2000) {
    fnToRunLater();
    hasRun = true;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 2e8; i++) {
    // some expensive operations
  }
}
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
if (!hasRun) {
  fnToRunLater();
}
console.log('done');
```

(warning: below snippet containing the code above will *block* your browser for a bit, depending on your hardware)

```js
// look at the timing in your browser console, not the snippet console

console.log('start');
let hasRun = false;
const fnToRunLater = () => console.log('hi');
const startTime = Date.now();
function test() {
  const now = Date.now();
  if (!hasRun && now - startTime > 2000) {
    fnToRunLater();
    hasRun = true;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < 2e8; i++) {
    // some expensive operations
  }
}
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
test();
if (!hasRun) {
  fnToRunLater();
}
console.log('done');
```

If an individual `test` takes too long, and the timeout isn't accurate enough (eg, if a test takes 400ms and this takes the difference from 1800ms to 2200ms, and that 200ms of inaccuracy is too much), then you'll have to change the `test` code so that it does multiple checks inside.